# How to set out an sql string without getting newline in constant error

Tags: c#, sql, string

This is daft but I am declaring a sql string for an  sqlcommand and I am having to write it all on one line as

```
string strSQL = "SELECT [Year],[Week No],StartDate,EndDate,Dept,[Clock No],RTRIM(Name)+' '+   RTRIM(initial) as Name,[Own Hours],[Other Hours],[Total Hours],[OT Premium] FROM [Wages].[CHHours] Where [Year]=@WageYear and [Week No]=@Week Order by  [Year] DESC, [Week No] DESC,Dept,[Clock No]" ;
```

because otherwise I get the newline in constant error but this looks REALLY ugly and hard to read. In vb it would use the  &_ to continue and as c# is not white space sensitive (I thought) I should write it like this

```
string strSQL = "SELECT [Year],[Week No],StartDate,EndDate,Dept,[Clock No],
              RTRIM(Name)+' '+ RTRIM(initial) as Name,[Own Hours],[Other Hours],
               [Total Hours],[OT Premium] 
               FROM [Wages].[CHHours] 
               Where [Year]=@WageYear and [Week No]=@Week 
               Order by  [Year] DESC, [Week No] DESC,Dept,[Clock No]" ;
```

or do I have to do to

```
string strSQL = "SELECT [Year],[Week No],StartDate,EndDate,Dept,[Clock No],";

string strSQL = strSQL+" RTRIM(Name)+' '+ RTRIM(initial) as Name,[Own Hours]";

string strSQL = strSQL+",[Other Hours],[Total Hours],[OT Premium] ";

string strSQL = strSQL+"FROM [Wages].[CHHours] ";

string strSQL = strSQL+" Where [Year]=@WageYear and [Week No]=@Week ";

string strSQL = strSQL+"Order by  [Year] DESC, [Week No] DESC,Dept,[Clock No]" ;
```

Which strikes me as something very old!

What is the best way please
Ian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the @ symbol,
eg

```
string strSQL = @"SELECT [Year],[Week No],StartDate,EndDate,Dept,[Clock No],
         RTRIM(Name)+' '+ RTRIM(initial) as Name,[Own Hours],[Other Hours],
           [Total Hours],[OT Premium] 
           FROM [Wages].[CHHours] 
           Where [Year]=@WageYear and [Week No]=@Week 
           Order by  [Year] DESC, [Week No] DESC,Dept,[Clock No]" ;
```

That might work?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
string strSQL = "SELECT [Year],[Week No],StartDate,EndDate,Dept,[Clock No]," 
                + " RTRIM(Name)+' '+ RTRIM(initial) as Name,[Own Hours]" 
                + ",[Other Hours],[Total Hours],[OT Premium] "
                + "FROM [Wages].[CHHours] "
                + " Where [Year]=@WageYear and [Week No]=@Week " 
                + "Order by [Year] DESC, [Week No] DESC,Dept,[Clock No]";
```

Comment: Not bad, but the @ symbol method involves less typing.

Comment: Interesting, wouldn't this cause a string concatenation each time this code get's run, or perhaps the C# compiler can optimize this away at compile time?
Also you haven't kept the new lines in the SQL Text :( so it maybe hard to read in SQL Profiler or ????

Answer (score 0):

```
string strSQL = @"SELECT [Year],[Week No],StartDate,EndDate,Dept,[Clock No],
     RTRIM(Name)+' '+ RTRIM(initial) as Name,[Own Hours],[Other Hours],
       [Total Hours],[OT Premium] 
       FROM [Wages].[CHHours] 
       Where [Year]=@WageYear and [Week No]=@Week 
       Order by  [Year] DESC, [Week No] DESC,Dept,[Clock No]" ;

//Now replace the @... with your desired data
strSQL = strSQL.Replace("@WageYear",your year).Replace("@Week ",your week);

//Or in multiple lines
strSQL = strSQL.Replace("@WageYear",your year);
strSQL = strSQL.Replace("@Week ",your week);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You should be very careful about doing the string replaces, you could be opening yourself upto a SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the two if you add in information from a text box to your query. Something like this

```
string strSQL = "SELECT [Year],[Week No],StartDate,EndDate,Dept,'" + textBox1.Text +  "'[Clock No],"
 +@" RTRIM(Name)+' '+ RTRIM(initial) as Name,[Own Hours]
 ,[Other Hours],[Total Hours],[OT Premium] 
 FROM [Wages].[CHHours] 
 Where [Year]=@WageYear and [Week No]=@Week  
 Order by [Year] DESC, [Week No] DESC,Dept,[Clock No]";
```